# How to trigger the event associated with maximize in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, maximize-window

Consider the following code:

```
Window myWindow = new MyWindowSubclass();
myWindow.BringIntoView();
myWindow.Show();

// Code which is effective as pressing the maximize button
```

Also, how to detect if the window is indeed in maximized state.

Comment: Do you want to target Windows.Forms or WPF? You code looks like WPF, but your question has both tags.

Comment: @Frédéric: I want to target WPF.I will remove winforms for every ones convenience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In WPF, you can use the [WindowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate.aspx) property:

```
myWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

You can of course query that property to obtain the current window state:

```
if (myWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized) {
    // Window is currently maximized.
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed :).
BTW, its ok to maximize a maximized window right?

Comment: @Gunner, maximizing a already maximized window is okay: it will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

For WinForms, you can use

```
bool maximized = this.WindowState == System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

to test if the window is maximized.

The `SizeChanged` and `Resize` events should capture all changes to the window state.

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms, do

```
// Code which is effective as pressing the maximize button
myWindow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Of course you can test it the same way:

```
if (myWindow.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized) { ... }
```